# Could this 'the way (that)' be replaced by 'how' without semantic change?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

> They were in civilian clothes, and I thought, Cops––until I saw the
>   baseball bat and started to turn, hearing, "Hey, you!"
>    I
>   hesitated.
>    "What's in that brief case?" they said, and if
>   they'd asked me anything else I might have stood still. But at the
>   question a wave of shame and outrage shook me and I ran, still heading
>   for Jack. But I was in strange territory now and someone, for some
>   reason, had removed the manhole cover and I felt myself plunge down,
>   down; a long drop that ended upon a load of coal that sent up a cloud
>   of dust, and I lay in the black dark upon the black coal no longer
>   running, hiding or concerned, hearing the shifting of the coal, as
>   from somewhere above their voices came floating down.
>    "You see
>   **the way** he went down, zoom! I was just fixing to slug the bastard."
>  (Ralph Ellison, Invisible Man)

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how) says ‘how’ has a meaning of ‘the way that.’ And I guess this could be applied on the example and ‘the way’ could be replaced by ‘how.’ I want to know if this is possible. And if yes, isn’t there any semantic difference?

Comment: *How he went down* is fine here, and the only difference is prosodic: *you SEE the WAY he went DOWN* vs *you SEE how he went DOWN*, and is perhaps more appropriate to lead up to *ZOOM!*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you can substitute them here. However, in this case, I believe Ellison used `the way` as a play on words:

`"a way"` can mean a path or route:

> "the store is that *way*"
>
> the way refers to the road that the store is on

`"the way"` refers to the manner in which something is done:

> "it wasn't what he said, it was the *way* he said it"
>
> (in this case it refers to the tone of voice, e.g. sarcastic or rude)

So here, Ellison uses the dual meanings of `way` to describe both the path he took, and the manner in which he took it. See [pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun/%22pun%22)